# Как получить информацию о составе заказа?

Tags: битрикс

Всем, привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить информацию о составе заказа?
В документации есть только описание [функции которая возвращает результат выборки записей из заказов в соответствии со своими параметрами](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/classes/csaleorder/csaleorder__getlist.41061294.php), ни слова про выборку товаров из  заказа. Еще нашел в пользовательской документации [описание формы просмотра заказа](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/store/sale/sale_order_detail.php#form) (ну и что толку от этой документации...). Помогите кто знает! Спасибо.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то поможет, вот решение:

```
CSaleBasket::GetList() фильтр по ORDER_ID
```

Документация разработчика [CSaleBasket::GetList()](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/sale/classes/csalebasket/csalebasket__getlist.4d82547a.php)